# How to output numpy array data into a ".dat" formatted file, that can be used in Texstudio?

Tags: arrays, numpy, file-io, format, latex

Example inputted data shown in Texstudio.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have two arrays x and y, then you can write them into a file *output.dat* with:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)

np.savetxt('output.dat', zip(x,y), fmt=['%.3f','%.3f'])
```

You may want to change the format.